# mongoimport not working for mongodb 4.4, not in bin folder

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am using mongodb 4.4 and while trying to import some JSON files getting some error of 'mongoimport' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function.

Comment: You can download the MongoDB 4.4 Database Tools separately at: [database tools](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools). Also, see the note: [MongoDB 4.4 Release Notes - tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.4/#tools).

Answer (score 8):

from MongoDB version 4.4 the database utility tools are  released separately hence you will need to download the files and copy it to your MongoDB directory

Steps on doing this.

1. download tools from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools  scroll down and click on MongoDB Database tools select your platform and download zip
2. unzip the file and copy the required tools [images to show this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YTVC.png)

3. copy file to your mongodb bin folder and paste for windows path is : C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, although very helpful, @yousouf9's link sent me to a page where the Database Tools version for Windows had "rpm" or "tgz" package options.

I then found this [mongodb installation instructions for Windows](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation-windows/), which led me to this [mongodb Database Tools download page](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools) where I was able to download the package in either MSI or zip.